# Parse SDK para Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, parse

Estou criando um projeto Windows Phone 8.1 usando o Visual Studio Community 2012. Este app deve se integrar com o backend provido pelo [Parse](http://www.parse.com). Bem, tentei seguir [este tutorial](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/windows_phone/existing), mas notei que o NuGet não instala o pacote... Abaixo segue a saída do NuGet:

```
Installing 'parse 1.3.2'.
Successfully installed 'parse 1.3.2'.
Adding 'parse 1.3.2' to youback.
Uninstalling 'parse 1.3.2'.
Successfully uninstalled 'parse 1.3.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'parse 1.3.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does 
not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package parse
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

O parse é um requisito muito importante para o meu aplicativo, por isso não tenho outra alternativa.

Alguém por um acaso teve esse tipo de problema? Como resolveu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente no momento o Parse não é suportado pelo windows phone 8.1.

Para trabalhar com a plataforma devemos utilizar o windows phone sdk 8. No site do parse existe um projeto quickstart que pode ser utilizado para facilitar o serviço. Este projeto funciona bem no visual studio 2012 comunnity.